# Basic jQuery contact form issue

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm stuck writing jQuery validation for a contact form. I wrote a simple code which would check whether an input form contained any characters; if there are any characters then it may continue to run the PHP code and send me the email. Otherwise, show an error box telling the customer to double-check that.  Here is the code:

```
    (function($){
       $('.required',$form).each(function(){
         var inputVal = $('form-element-name').val();
         var inputVal2 = $('form-element-email').val();

                if(inputVal == ''){
                    $('errorbox1').addClass('errormsg1');
                } 

                else if(inputVal2 == '') {
                    $('errorbox2').addclass('errormsg2');
                }
            }
     }
```

Inputval is the inputfield for the name and inputval2 is the inputfield for the e-mail. Furthermore, Errorbox1 is a container that is empty and the errormsg1 would be the class that would give the errorbox1 a background-image saying error.

[Here is a jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/U6xGA/3/).

Comment: Check JSLint on your fiddle example...there's a lot of errors in your coding which you need to fix before you can properly debug this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('errorbox1')` and `$('errorbox2')`

should be

`$('.errorbox1')` and `$('.errorbox2')` if class selector

or

`$('#errorbox1')` and `$('#errorbox2')` if ID selector

Note the dot/# before the errorbox1.

Below are references to class and ID selector,

http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/

http://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: @ShadAsinger Check evilunix answer, he posted additional bugs in your code. :P

Comment: Depends if errorbox1 is a class or an ID, in the later case it should be # instead of dot

Comment: @SKS wow you saved my life! Just what I was looking for! But how come it doesn't give the email and the name at the same time an error? But give the e-mail error after the name. Anyway, BIG THANKS!!!

Comment: Something really weird is happening... When I run the code on my own computer with the whole project it goes wrong and just skips the jquery code completely and goes on to the PHP. However, when I run it on jsFiddle everything just seems to work fine as expected. I have uploaded the website here: http://aasingercom.ipage.com/php/  , you can see the contact form at the footer if you scroll all the way down.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are missing the hash from your jQuery selectors - you should have `$('#form-element-name')` instead of `$('form-element-name')` - which will select elements based on their id.

Or - a dot to select by class instead.

You need to put your code inside the form's onsubmit event then `return false;` or use `e.preventDefault();` to cancel the form submission.

```
$('#your-form-id').submit(function() {
    // if error then cancel form submission
});
```

Comment: Really wierd. It does seem to work now but when I check I can see the errorbox flashing and it straight-away redirects me to the PHP that would essentially send me the email.

Comment: See above - cancel the form submission directly after showing the error message.

Comment: Good point. But I already done that but I didn't show that section of the code. I've edited the jsFiddle with the full jquery code http://jsfiddle.net/U6xGA/3/

Comment: Wherever your are adding the error class, the next line needs to return false.. Not sure what all the plugin code is for, seems to be overkill?

Comment: Something really weird is happening... When I run the code on my own computer with the whole project it goes wrong and just skips the jquery code completely and goes on to the PHP. However, when I run it on jsFiddle everything just seems to work fine as expected. I have uploaded the website here: http://aasingercom.ipage.com/php/  , you can see the contact form at the footer if you scroll all the way down.